# EF Core 3.1 have identity field without identity / remove identity increment

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

There are a lot of questions of how to use fluent API to set a columns as an identity column using:

`.UseIdentityColumn()`

However, I need the opposite - the primary key field, needs to be the table identity (for UPSERTS) however, I'd like to remove the identity spec.

In SSMS I can set the identity specification to `no` but I'd like to see if this is possible within the Fluent API.

I've tried:

Edit to update - the full code is:

```
builder.Entity<ModelClass>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
builder.Entity<ModelClass>()
                .Property(x => x.Id)
                .ValueGeneratedNever()                
                .HasAnnotation("DatabaseGenerated", DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

So, the ID column still needs to be key to the table `.HasKey(x => x.Id)` - but without the identity spec

The property Id is a key, and then told to not generate values. For me, in SQL server the table still has a "Identity Specification" = "yes" and then seed and increment values set.

Comment: I don't really understand your question, if you don't want an identity column, then don't use `UseIdentityColumn`.

Comment: It needs to be the primary key - so `.HasKey(x => x.id)` which by default enables identity specification

Comment: Stop using the `UseIdentityColumn` and it won't be an identity column. `ValueGeneratedNever` is likely helpful too.

Comment: Sorry, edited - the `UseIdentityColumn` was a test - but the edited code above still has the PK with a SQL server ID specification... So the `ValueGeneratedNever` doesn't stop this behaviour.

Comment: But I'm telling you that it *does* work. You only need to specify the key with `HasKey` and then use `ValueGeneratedNever`. You do not need `HasAnnotation`

Comment: An IDENTITY column isn't a key, it's just an autogenerated column. To mark a property as key one *has* to use either `HasKey` or use the `Key` attribute. Without this, the entity has no key and EF will complain.

Comment: Have you actually changed the table column to *not* be an `IDENTITY`?

Comment: I've just updated the question with the full code - for me, the identity spec is always set!

Comment: The code you show here does **not** create an identity column. And you don't need the `HasAnnotation` part either.

Comment: @RemarkLima have you recreated the table or modified the column specification? Removing `UseIdentityColumn` won't modify an existing table

Comment: OK, nuked all the tables, rolled back the migrations and it's worked as expected. Thanks for the help. @PanagiotisKanavos and DavidG - if you put and answer I'll accept

Answer (score 0):

1- update your entity using fluent API as below

```
entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.None);
```

2- Create new migration and make sure that your property has below configuration in new generated migration code in UP method

```
.Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.None)
```

then update your DB

[image]

Comment: There is no need for that first line of code, it doesn't do anything, and the second one does pretty much the same thing as using `.ValueGeneratedNever()`. So your answer is just complicating things unnecessarily.

Comment: first line for fluent api and second one for making sure that migration generated as expected to work, what's wrong in this ?

Comment: Like I said, the first line doesn't do anything, it's the second one that does the work. Also, the second line should be `.HasAnnotation...`

Comment: dear please read my comment carefully, second line it'll be in generated migration code in up method not in fluent api, the first line will be in fluent api

Comment: No it won't, at least not in EF Core, perhaps you are talking about EF6?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228792/discussion-between-mohamed-adel-and-davidg).

Comment: The annotation isn't necessary either in EF 6 or EF Core, even for migrations. EF won't create an IDENTITY column out of the blue.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos EF Core I think will make an identity column by default, need to test it.

Comment: he needs to remove identity auto increment

Answer (score 0):

.HasAnnotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy",
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Metadata.NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.SerialColumn)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).